# Java Updating Program questions

Tags: java, file, sockets, object, updates

I have a program that updates files on the computer using information sent by a server, using sockets. The way I had it worked, but i wanted to make it more intuitive, simpler, more reliable, etc. here is the previous code:

```
int filesize = 6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;

    /**
     *  receive file
     */
    try {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[filesize];
        java.io.InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        bytesRead = inStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(
                "C:\\Program Files\\AVTECH\\NPS\\Files\\bin\\NPS Game.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream buffOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                fileOutStream);
        current = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead = inStream.read(byteArray, current,
                    (byteArray.length - current));
            if (bytesRead >= 0)
                current += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > -1);

        buffOutStream.write(byteArray, 0, current);
        buffOutStream.flush();
        buffOutStream.close();
        inStream.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        socket.close();
    }
```

as you can see, in the `do, while` loop, it is using the input stream to get the data. now that i've updated my program, i have the stream sending an object called `UpdateObject`, which holds the `byte[]` array along with the file directory. here is that code:

```
    int filesize = 6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;
    try {
        byte[] byteArray = o.getFile();
         java.io.InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
         bytesRead = inStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(o.getPath());
        BufferedOutputStream buffOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                fileOutStream);
        current = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead = inStream.read(byteArray, current,
                    (byteArray.length - current));
            if (bytesRead >= 0)
                current += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > -1);

        buffOutStream.write(byteArray, 0, current);
        buffOutStream.flush();
        buffOutStream.close();
        inStream.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now my question is this: how do i change it so instead of using the `instream`, to use just a byte[] object in the `UpdateObject` sent over the socket? i've done some google searching, but i dont feel like i know the right question to ask. any help would be great! thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing most of your code inside the try catch block with:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(
    UpdateObject.getDirectory()+"\\NPS Game.txt");
fileOutStream.write(UpdateObject.getBytes()); //this is the byte[] array
fileOutStream.close();
```

Hope this helps.